# QR Code Live Scanning in BlackBerry OS 6.0

Tags: blackberry, qr-code, zxing

I want to Implement a QR Code Reader In BlackBerry Os 6. I try the following Code On the Basis of KB Article [How to use the Barcode API](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-the-Barcode-API/ta-p/574569).

```
public class ScanScreen extends MainScreen implements BarcodeDecoderListener 
{ 
    private LabelField match; 
    private BarcodeScanner scanner; 
 
    public ScanScreen() 
    { 
        match = new LabelField("Scanning..."); 
        add(match); 
        Vector supported = new Vector(); 
        
        supported.addElement(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE); 
        
        Hashtable hints = new Hashtable(); 
        
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, supported); 
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        
        BarcodeDecoder decoder = new BarcodeDecoder(hints);
        
      try 
        { 
            scanner = new BarcodeScanner(decoder, this); 
            add(scanner.getViewfinder()); 
            scanner.startScan();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            match.setText("Exception");
            invalidate();
        } 
    } 
 
    public void barcodeDecoded(String rawText) 
    { 
        match.setText("Found: " + rawText); 
        invalidate();
    } 
 
    public void close() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            scanner.stopScan(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
 
        super.close(); 
    } 
}
```

The Code not working. **It do not  recognize QR codes. I try to focus on different QR codes. But it not decode The qrcodes.Also It not Thrown Any exceptions.**  Please Help me....

I tried using these Devices: **BB pearl 9105 and BB Storm 9530**

Comment: What do you mean with not working? I've used this API and worked for me.

Comment: @MisterSmith not worked means it is not recognize the qr codes. Comes the camera view and not go to barcodeDecoded().. ie the qr codes not recognised..

Comment: How it will test on simulators...

Comment: Are you sure that method is not called? Put a log line at first place inside the method to check that it is not hit. And about the QRs you are using, make sure they are QRCodes and not other similar format, and print them in good quality. Test with good ambient light if camera doesn't have flash.

Comment: So what happens? You are left on the camera? Is there an exception?

Comment: No exception found.. But it do not recognize the qr codes.. I try to focus camera on different qrcodes But it do not decode it...

Comment: @Ajmal ..I am also facing the same problem ...I have BB 9800 device  OS 6.0 and I tried the QR scanner Demo on this ..but unfortunately it's not working ..did you find any solution

Comment: @Anzy_ i think, it solved in 9105(OS 6.0) by adding a screencapture or inputstimulation permission( http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissions.html) request at app starting, and accepted answer worked in OS 5.0. Also try the qr code apps from the bb appworld check it is working in your device or not

Comment: @Ajmal .. I tested this demo http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.in/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html on Curve 9300 having 5.0 os ..sometimes it Scan the qr code perfectly ..but some time it doesn't open the camera View .. insted of camera I get a blankScreen ..

Comment: try to request inputstimulation permission..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the sample from the following link.It will help you

http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.com/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html

Comment: i tried this also. But the same result. I use the devices pearl and storm. But both not recognize qr code....

Answer (score 0):

I'm painfully new to BB development, but I notice you pass "this" as the decoderlistener parameter, perhaps that's causing a problem?

```
    BarcodeDecoder decoder = new BarcodeDecoder(hints);
    BarcodeDecoderListener decoderListener = new BarcodeDecoderListener()
        {
            public void barcodeDecoded(String rawText)
            {
                displayMessage(rawText);
            }
        };

  try 
    { 
        scanner = new BarcodeScanner(decoder, decoderListener)
        add(scanner.getViewfinder()); 
        scanner.startScan();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        match.setText("Exception");
        invalidate();
    } 
}
```